# How to perform unknown gesture recognizers action?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uigesturerecognizer

I have splitViewController with default pan gesture on its view. I want to perform gesture action of this gesture recognizer programmatically. Is it possible to do?
I did not create this gesture recognizer and did not setup selector method to handle it!

Comment: You can get the gesture recognizers for this view by doing `view.gestureRecognizers`. In there, find the one you're looking for and then trigger an action.

Comment: But why don't you just call the action the gesture recognizer triggers?